# What are appropriate use cases for writing own deconstructors in C#7?

Tags: c#

C# 7 has a nice new language feature: The De**con**structor.  It is possible to use it for value tuples for instance. However, I can also create my own deconstructors for my own classes. Why would I do that? My classes have properties. So individual items can be accessed anyway.

Comment: Convenience, and possible future use in pattern matching

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Deconstruction offers considerable brevity and clarity over the traditional alternative, and provides support for a fully functional-style of programming.

Consider this simple, one-line deconstructor example from Microsoft:

```
var (first, middle, last) = LookupName(id1);
```

To do the same thing in the traditional object-oriented way, you would have to write code that looks something like this:

```
class Name
{
    public string First { get; set; }
    public string Middle { get; set; }
    public string Last { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
var name = someObject.LookupName(id1);

var first = name.First;
var middle = name.Middle;
var last = name.Last;
```

Even if you returned a tuple, it would still take 4 lines of code, and you would lose your property name mapping:

```
var name = someObject.LookupName(id1);

var first = name.Item1;
var middle = name.Item2;
var last = name.Item3;
```

Comment: Why witte "var first = name.First". You can just use "name.First". Less lines of code and no deconstructors needed.

Comment: @Daan Sure, but what if your logic is more complex? How about `var family, given; if (user.Culture.FamilyNameFirst) { (family, given) = user.Name; } else { (given, family) = user.Name; }`?

Comment: @Jules: Unless there is something I'm missing, aren't you better off defining such logic in the `Name` property itself? It seems weird to put the "logic of the order" outside of the class that returns items in a given order.

Comment: The downside (or risk) is that something could get deconstructed (and/or deleted) that wasn't intended.  I think if objects have references to other objects, there may be a need for this (similar to database cases where there are foreign keys in a table)

Answer (score 2):

"Use cases" is a slightly strange verbiage for the question. This doesn't really allow you to do anything you couldn't before. It's simply neater in some cases.

The only major thing I can think of is that it gives you some limited compile-time checking. For example, suppose you have a `UsAddress` class. You have line 1, line 2, city, state, and zip. You can deconstruct into variables `var (line1, line2, city, state, zip) = ObtainAddress()`. Now suppose you want to add a line 3. This spot will now be a compilation error because it doesn't match the deconstructor and you can evaluate what you need to do about line 3 at every call site. The alternative would be:

```
var address = ObtainAddress();
var line1 = address.Line1;
// ...
```

In this case, there would be no compilation error for the new field. Whether that's good or not is, of course, its own debate.

A lot of the ideas that went into C# 6 and 7 were polishing and easing pain points and it seems like a lot of people complained about the lack of first-class support for tuples in the language. So it isn't so much "use case" as it is syntactic sugar.

Comment: Of course if you don't want a compile error when the number of fields changes, you can add an overload to continue providing the old version.